# I need to create a loop so that my decimal "unitprice" will check for other decimals under the same nam

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops

I need to create a loop so that when I try to come up with a subtotal from a shopping cart it will keep checking to see if there are more items in the cart. My cart is a list box at this point in time. I've already declared my decimal as unitprice to pull the data from my access table.  I will also need to add shipping(2$ per item), tax (@ 7%), and finally tally up a total. I'm a complete newbie at this and any help would greatly be appreciated.  I am using a combination of c# and asp.net in visual studio 2010.
C# code from cart page

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private CartItemList cart;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cart = CartItemList.GetCart();
        if (!IsPostBack)
            this.DisplayCart();
    }

    private void DisplayCart()
    {
        lstBox.Items.Clear();
        CartItem item;
        for (int i = 0; i < cart.Count; i++)
        {
            item = cart[i];
            lstBox.Items.Add(item.Display());
        }
    }

    protected void clrBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cart.Count > 0)
        {
            cart.Clear();
            lstBox.Items.Clear();
        }
    }

    protected void  rmvBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cart.Count > 0)
        {
            if (lstBox.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                cart.RemoveAt(lstBox.SelectedIndex);
                this.DisplayCart();
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Please select the item you want to remove.";
            }
        }
    }

    protected void checkoutBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Code from Order Page in c#

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Product selectedProduct;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            ddlproducts.DataBind();

        selectedProduct = this.GetSelectedProduct();
        lblName.Text = selectedProduct.Name;
        lblShortDescription.Text = selectedProduct.ShortDescription;
        lblLongDescription.Text = selectedProduct.LongDescription;
        lblUnitPrice.Text = selectedProduct.UnitPrice.ToString("c");
    }

    private Product GetSelectedProduct()
    {
        DataView BooksTable = (DataView)
        AccessDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        BooksTable.RowFilter =
            "ProductID = '" + ddlproducts.SelectedValue + "'";
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)BooksTable[0];

        Product p = new Product();
        p.ProductID = row["ProductID"].ToString();
        p.Name = row["Name"].ToString();
        p.ShortDescription = row["ShortDescription"].ToString();
        p.LongDescription = row["LongDescription"].ToString();
        p.UnitPrice = (decimal)row["UnitPrice"];
        //p.ImageFile = row["Image File"].ToString();
        return p;
    }

    protected void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            CartItemList cart = CartItemList.GetCart();
            CartItem cartItem = cart[selectedProduct.ProductID];
            if (cartItem == null)
            {
                cart.AddItem(selectedProduct, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                cartItem.AddQuantity(1);
            }
            Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

cartitemlist code in c#(I copied all of this code from my book btw. I have no idea how to program.)

```
public class CartItemList
{
    private List<CartItem> cartItems;

    public CartItemList()
    {
        cartItems = new List<CartItem>();
    }

    public int Count {
        get { return cartItems.Count; }
    }

    public CartItem this[int index]
    {
        get { return cartItems[index]; }
        set { cartItems[index] = value; }
    }

    public CartItem this[string id]
    {
        get {
            foreach (CartItem c in cartItems)
                if (c.Product.ProductID == id) return c;
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static CartItemList GetCart()
    {
        CartItemList cart = (CartItemList) HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];
        if (cart == null)
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] = new CartItemList();
        return (CartItemList) HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];
    }

    public void AddItem(Product product, int quantity)
    {
        CartItem c = new CartItem(product, quantity);
        cartItems.Add(c);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        cartItems.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        cartItems.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code? That will be helpful.

Comment: This is the code from c# on my cart page.

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't let me past it in the comment.  I edited my original question though.

Comment: Looks to me like you may need to post the code for your implementation of CartItemList. I suspect that the problem is likely in the GetCart method if it is not returning the entire list.

Comment: @Kevin posted in my an edit of my original post.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to fetch all Items from cart one by one and want to return the total price of the cart. Is this what you want -

```
double total = 0;
foreach(CartItem cartItem in CartItemList.GetCart())
{
   total+= cartItem.Price * cartItem.Quantity
}
```

Comment: Or is it that your `GetCart()` method not returning the items correctly?

Comment: To my limited coding ability(I copied all the previous code for this project from my textbook.) That looks feasible.  I also forgot to mention that I need this to post into a textbox.  I'm sorry I'm new to this. I know that would have been important information from the beginning.

Comment: The GetCart() is returning the items to my cart correctly, but I just need to produce in a text box the subtotal of the cart, add $2 shipping per item in the cart in another text box, multiply the tax rate at 7% in another text box, and then produce a total in a final text box.